# Play & pause video using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, youtube, automation

My aim is to automate play/pause YouTube video present on the web page using selenium.

How to play/pause YouTube video with Java code for Selenium?

Comment: *"i need it in java"*  We need a specific questions & signs of effort.  Voting to close.

Comment: what kind of video ? (youtube,...) Normally, a simple click on the video can pause/play it.

Comment: how to do play/pause with code ? yes this is youtube video

Comment: ok thx @Andrew now please give me solution for that i open video using get("/learnerhome.htm#/basketState/139/basketItemStates/196674"); and now i need to play this video

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a cool guy so i'll post some code here.

```
driver.get("video link"); // open your browser at youtube video.

WebElement video = driver.findElement(By.id("id video")); // use the id of the video to find it

video.click(); // play the video

// implicite wait
//code .....

video.click(); // pause de video
```

With pracctice you'll add some conditions like if the video's lenghtbar is finish get another video else blablabla .

Comment: thx it works .. good work

Comment: e1che, how are you getting the id of video ? from where i can get that id.. i tried it but i am unable to make it work :(

Comment: @RohitArora You should use the Inspector tool (on Mozilla for exemple) and it will help to locate the element you are looking for. http://imgur.com/a/cSpME

Comment: Can we use xpath, css selector or something else? because that doesn't have an id...

Comment: @RohitArora Sure, i prefer to use cssSelector, it will look like this  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#movie_player"));