# Unable to play YouTube video using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, html5-video

Spec: Chrome: Version 81.0.4044.113 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I would like to play HTML video by using Selenium. The link to the video can be accessed from:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXbfZL5kttM

The closes thread that addressing this problem can be found online such as [OP1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59116165/6446053).

Based on the suggestion provided by [RP1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51765103/6446053), the following code were drafted:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"Browsers\chromedriver.exe",
                           options=chrome_options)
browser.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXbfZL5kttM")
WebDriverWait(browser, 40).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@src='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXbfZL5kttM']")))
WebDriverWait(browser, 40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='ytp-large-play-button ytp-button']"))).click()
```

However, Selenium throw an error at line : `WebDriverWait(browser, 40).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`.

> Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//iframe[contains(@src,'https://www.youtube.com')]"}

Or as per [RP2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51764669/6446053):

```
required_frame = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'https://www.youtube.com')]")
browser.switch_to.frame(required_frame)
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@aria-label='Play']")
element.click()
```

Similarly, a similar error was thrown at line `browser.find_element_by_xpath`.

Are there possibilities that YouTube had changed their framework (e.g., `iframe`) that lead the previous suggestion not working anymore? I try to check all available `iframe` as suggested from this [OP3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3774015/6446053), but I am a bit clueless on how to find the correct `iframe` suitable for my case.

I appreciate for any help.

**Edit 1**:

As suggested by [OP4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162632/6446053):

```
video = browser.findElement(By.id("id video")) # Use the id of the video to find it.
video.click()
```

No error, but the video not playing.

Comment: what is the link for the video you are trying to play?

Comment: Hi @0m3r, please refer to the edited thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to locate the `iframe`, there is no such one.
So, your code should look like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXbfZL5kttM")

WebDriverWait(browser, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Play']"))).click()
```

I hope it helps you!

Comment: To follow up, how do you know there is no such iframe? This knowledge may help me in the future if I would like to play HTML video from different website.

Comment: @balandongiv, you are welcome! You can inspect the page in Developer Tools in Google Chrome, for example.